# How to sort references according to the order in .bib file and make some of them in bold?

Tags: beamer, bibtex, natbib

I am preparing a presentation in Beamer and I am using natbib and the references are in a separate .bib file.

I want to sort the references according to the order in .bib file and to make same of them in bold, but I cannot find any solution in the net.

here is an example of my code

```
     \documentclass{beamer}

        \usetheme[menuwidth={0.3\paperwidth}]{erlangen}

        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
     \renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
    \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsubsection*{\bibname }}
\nocite{*} 
  \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{References}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    \bibliography{biblio}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and an example of my biblio.bib file

```
@article{art1,
author={First Last},
title={A fictitious journal article},
year=1900,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}

@article{art2,
author={Assd},
title={A fictitious journal article},
year=1900,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did  you select the order to put them in the .bib file  and why? There's probably a better way to do it. As for making some bold, we've got a few questions about highlighting personal publications here. Those might help.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/bibtex-order-references-as-in-bibtex-file If this does not help, please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: @smacarter this does not help me I got a lot of error, I provided a minimial example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the theme from https://github.com/haechi/beamer-erlangen

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[menuwidth={0.3\paperwidth}]{erlangen}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsubsection*{\bibname }}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*} 

\begin{frame}
    \cite{art2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{References}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A quick hack hack to make individual entries bold:

```
@article{art1,
author={First Last},
title={A fictitious journal article},
year=1900,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}

@article{art2,
author={Assd},
title={A fictitious journal article},
year=1900,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}

@article{art3,
author={Bold, \bfseries{}James},
title={A fictitious journal article},
year=1900,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}

@article{art4,
author={\normalfont Assd},
title={A fictitious journal article},
year=1900,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}
```

[image]

Comment: when I used "unsrtnat" the references appear as they are cited in the text and not in the order of .bib file

Comment: @FarahMind Yes, but if you do `\nocite{*}` before citing any references yourself, they should appear as in the bib file.